# How do I constantly refresh a getTime output?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a little clock using getTime(), but the output won't refresh. I have tried this:

```html
<p id="clock"></p>
```

```js
var i;
for (i=0; i < 5; i++){
    var date = getTime;
    var time = time.getHour() + ":" + time.getMinute() + ":" + time.getSecond()
    getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;
}
```

Though it just keeps my tab in a constant state of loading. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: From this code, you will see only the result of the final iteration of for loop.

Comment: Try loooking up 'setInterval' here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: I found out that my code was very flawed, but Atr0x's code worked with a bit of correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your code inside setInterval()

```
let i = 5;
const timer = setInterval(() => {
    var date = getTime;
    var time = time.getHour() + ":" + time.getMinute() + ":" + time.getSecond()
    getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;

    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
       clearInterval(timer)
   }
}, 1000);
```

So setInterval() lets your code run asyncrounously, that means it doesnt block the rest of the execution, because it runs "seperately" (I would like to describe it better, but my english skills are lacking).

setInterval runs your code every 1000 ms (as specified) forever, unless you dont clear it with clearInterval(). If you want to make a timer it is quiet useful.

this () => {} is an arrow function. You can also use function(){}, if you want, in this case it makes no difference.

Here is the w3schools reference for setInterval(): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

and here is the MDN reference to asynchronous javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Good luck with your project ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
setInterval (function refresh(){
  var fecha = new Date();
  var hora = fecha.getHours();
  var minutos = fecha.getMinutes();
  var segundos = fecha.getSeconds();

  var textoHora = `
    ${hora}:${minutos}:${segundos}
  `;
  document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = textoHora;
}, 1000);
```